# Number of times the custom sort function is called

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector of objects v which is sorted with a custom function `sortproc`:

`std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sortproc);`

Before sorting the array, I would like to know in advance how many times sortproc will be called.

What have I tried? I tried cloning the vector, then sorting the copy and count how many times sortproc is called. I do this by incrementing a counter. Then, after sorting the copy I read the value of the counter and sort the original vector again. This works but is very inefficient because it's doing the whole job twice. Is it possible to do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: I smell an XY, better yet, an AZ problem here. (the attempted solution is presumably as far from the real one as A is from Z.)

Comment: It's not really possible to know precisely how many times `sortproc` will be called without knowing the exact implementation of `std::sort`, as well as the actual permutation of data that's in your vector.  This seems like a strange thing to want to predict.  You can _estimate_ the rate of growth of the number of times `sortproc` would be called on a randomized vector of length N, based on the algorithmic guarantees in the C++ standard (ie. O(N log N)), but nothing absolute.  Even big-Oh only gives asymptotic trends, not absolutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly not. Two obstacles that spring to mind are:

1) the standard doesn't define what algorithm `std::sort` uses, so portable code cannot know exactly how many comparisons are performed other than just trying it.

2) even if you did know the algorithm, I think that for sensible sorting algorithms figuring out the number of comparisons required can't be any easier than figuring out the number of inversions, which itself has the same complexity as sorting. So you aren't going to get a massively more efficient solution.

The workaround for 2 would be if the `sort` algorithm was such that the number of comparisons doesn't depend on how close to ordered the data is, only on the size of the data. It's not *too* difficult to design a sort algorithm with that property. It would probably be less efficient than a "real" sort algorithm, but could well be more efficient than sorting twice.

So just for example in a merge sort, normally when one side of the merge is exhausted you copy the remainder of the other side straight into the destination. If at that point you did a bunch of extra redundant comparisons solely to make up the numbers, then the number of comparisons wouldn't depend on the order of the input. And the number of pointless comparisons would be worst case half the total, so it shouldn't be any worse than sorting twice. This isn't a "fair" comparison with `std::sort`, though, because merge sort isn't a valid algorithm for `std::sort` anyway: it uses too much extra memory.

Sorting networks use a fixed number of comparisons too, but are also no good for `std::sort` because you need to know the number of items to design the network...